# Ending tail -f after print n lines

Tags: command-line, bash, tail

I have the following.

1. A Java process writing logs on file
2. A shell script starting
   the Java process.

I need to read the log file after start Java process to check correct starting.

I have try with `tail -f` but it remain append forever. I need `tail` stop after print n lines. There is a way like `-n` option for previuos lines?

Comment: Does your log file cleaned each time, after shell script run Java process?

Comment: I use log4j with append mode to write log file. It rotate after the file dimension raise up to 10MB.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can pipe the output of `tail -f` to `head` to limit the amount of lines shown:

```
tail -f [PATH] | head -n 100
```

to only show 100 lines in total.

Answer (score 7):

### New lines only

With the plain `tail -f`, the first 10 lines are from the file as it already exists:

```
tail -f file.log | head -30
```

writes 10 lines of `log.txt` when it is run, and 20 (n-10) lines that are added later.

With a log file, you normally use `-f` (`--follow`) to see the lines written in the future.

To see only the 30 lines that where written after `tail` was started,
limit the initial output to 0:

```
tail -f -n0 file.log | head -30
```